# How to color parts of character in HTML?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

On my website, I'm using a user rating with five stars. So each user can choose from one to five stars.

And I would like to show the average user rating, with partial colored stars. For example: The average rating is 3.5 stars, three stars should be colored completely, and the fourth star should be colored with 50% horizontal.

I'm using the [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/) for showing the stars. So each star is a character, not an image.

[image: 3.5 Stars]

Is there a solution for this, without using an image? Maybe with CSS?

Until now, I know only solutions to color complete characters with `style="color: yellow;"`, but I would like to color 50% of the fourth character...

Comment: would you mind sharing what you have achieved ?

Comment: Like mentioned, I can color complete stars with the given CSS code.

Comment: you want this in on hover ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by having 2 instances of 5 stars, 1 set is yellow stars and 1 is gray. Position the yellow one on top then set the width to a percentage and hide the overflow

```css
.rating {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1em;
 }
 
 .rating__overlay {
  color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 70%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.rating__base {
  color: #ccc;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="rating">
  <div class="rating__overlay">
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="rating__base">
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```